# Multiple requests for the same query in different controllers (on the same page)

Tags: angularjs, rest, angular-ui-router

I develop a SPA consisting of multiple controllers and views, using ui-router and Restangular. I noticed that I have to call the same URL from an API in two views (states) while running the app, both need info from the very same web service.

What's the best practice to make these two to share the same promise, in case that is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a service and inject it in your two controllers. The service would also keep a variable with the query you made. When you want to make the request just update that variable.

Answer (score 0):

If both states share a common parent, you can use ui-router's `resolve` when loading the parent state. That way you will make the query once, and the data will be available to that state and all children.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

Comment: That would help, thanks a lot! However, I tried to inject my own service into the .config-function, but cannot make that to work, as the service, that is my guess, is not initiated yet when the .config-function runs. Any idea why?

Comment: What are you trying to inject into the config function? Only providers are available at the time that the config function runs, so your service has not yet been instantiated. See here: https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/config-function